# turtle module seems to lack turtle.demo()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, demo

When I try to do the following in python 2.7.8 shell:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> turtle.demo()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    turtle.demo()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'demo'
```

This is the first time in my life I try using turtle, and assumed it would be installed when installing python. I can't find it anywhere on my computer and don't know how  to get it at the correct place. Can anybody please explain what I have to do to get at least the turtle.demo() working?

Comment: Okay, I just tried the following in powershell (windows 7): python -m pydoc turtle. Which gave me the location of the file, being C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\turtle.py. I am scrolling through the document and it indeed doesn't have anything called demo(), though there is a function called demo1() and one called demo2(). both don't do anything in the python shell either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `demo1()` and `demo2()` are defined under a `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement, don't try to run them from inside a Python shell, instead run the turtle.py library as if it were a standalone Python program:

```
python C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\turtle.py
```

that should invoke the two demonstration routines, one after the other.  Worth watching just to see the *undo* feature in action.